# Mock windows media to test responsive hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, media-queries

I am trying to test the following implementation.

```
import React from "react";
import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const isSM = useMediaQuery({ maxWidth: 767 });
  const isMD = useMediaQuery({ minWidth: 768, maxWidth: 1023 });
  const isLG = useMediaQuery({ minWidth: 1024 });

  console.log(`isSM:${isSM} isMD:${isMD} isLG:${isLG}`);

  return <>{`isSM:${isSM} isMD:${isMD} isLG:${isLG}`}</>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

How can I mock it so that isLG can be set to true?
And similarly to be able to set isSM and isMD to be true for other tests?

Tried the following but all 3 (isSM, isMD, isLG) are always false.

```
function mockMatchMedia(query) {
    return Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
        writable: true,
        value: jest.fn().mockImplementation((mediaQuery) => ({
        matches: mediaQuery.includes(query),
        media: mediaQuery,
        onchange: null,
        addListener: jest.fn(), 
        removeListener: jest.fn(),
        addEventListener: jest.fn(),
        removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
        dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
        })),
    });
}

test("renders the component", () => {
    mockMatchMedia('min-width: 1024px');
    mount(<MyComponent />);

    // the console log in component prints false for all wrongly. 
    // Was expecting isLG to be true.

    // assertions
}
```

UPDATE:

The following still prints out false for all 3.

```
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import { MatchMediaMock, create } from 'match-media-mock';

export const matchSnapshot = (reactElement: React.ReactElement) => {
  const instance = renderer.create(reactElement);
  const tree = instance.toJSON();

  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
};

interface MockWindow extends Window {
    matchMedia: MatchMediaMock
}

test("renders", () => {
    global.window.matchMedia = create();
    (window as unknown as MockWindow).matchMedia.setConfig({
      type: 'screen',
      width: 700
    })
    matchSnapshot(
      <MyComponent />
    );
  });
```

Comment: Don't test implementations like hooks.  Test the rendered behavior.

Comment: Hi @possum . This is in a project we don't directly maintain with over 400 tests that has these types of tests. A recent change needs this mocking. Thus looking for a solution for the mock, not looking to change 400 odd tests.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.  It's bad testing practice and you're finding there's not a lot of resources for mocking hooks because hooks are not designed to be mocked.

Comment: @possum I am not mocking the hook. Mock needs to happen on window.matchmedia.

Comment: Then you should reword your question.  You lead with "I am trying to test the following implementation.  How can I mock it (*the implementation*) so that isLG can be set to true?"

Answer (score 1):

The [match-media-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/match-media-mock) package can help you to create the mock for `window.matchMedia` easily.

E.g.

`jest.setup.js`:

```js
import matchMediaMock from 'match-media-mock';

global.window.matchMedia = matchMediaMock.create();
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-extended', './jest.setup.js']
};
```

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const isSM = useMediaQuery({ maxWidth: 767 });
  const isMD = useMediaQuery({ minWidth: 768, maxWidth: 1023 });
  const isLG = useMediaQuery({ minWidth: 1024 });

  console.log(`isSM:${isSM} isMD:${isMD} isLG:${isLG}`);

  return <>{`isSM:${isSM} isMD:${isMD} isLG:${isLG}`}</>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

**1. Testing recipe using RTL**:

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MatchMediaMock } from 'match-media-mock';
import MyComponent from '.';

interface MockWindow extends Window {
  matchMedia: MatchMediaMock
}

describe('76305067', () => {
  test('should be sm', () => {
    (window as unknown as MockWindow).matchMedia.setConfig({
      type: 'screen',
      width: 700,
    })
    render(<MyComponent />)
  })
  test('should be md', () => {
    (window as unknown as MockWindow).matchMedia.setConfig({
      type: 'screen',
      width: 1000,
    })
    render(<MyComponent />)
  })
  test('should be lg', () => {
    (window as unknown as MockWindow).matchMedia.setConfig({
      type: 'screen',
      width: 1200,
    })
    render(<MyComponent />)
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76305067/index.test.tsx (18.06 s)
  76305067
    ✓ should be sm (54 ms)
    ✓ should be md (7 ms)
    ✓ should be lg (5 ms)

  console.log
    isSM:true isMD:false isLG:false

      at MyComponent (stackoverflow/76305067/index.tsx:9:11)

  console.log
    isSM:false isMD:true isLG:false

      at MyComponent (stackoverflow/76305067/index.tsx:9:11)

  console.log
    isSM:false isMD:false isLG:true

      at MyComponent (stackoverflow/76305067/index.tsx:9:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        19.631 s, estimated 24 s
```

**2. Testing recipe using `react-dom`**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { unmountComponentAtNode, render } from 'react-dom';
import { MatchMediaMock } from 'match-media-mock';
import MyComponent from '.';

interface MockWindow extends Window {
  matchMedia: MatchMediaMock
}

describe('76305067', () => {
  let container: HTMLDivElement | null = null;
  beforeEach(() => {
    container = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(container);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    if (container) {
      unmountComponentAtNode(container);
      container.remove();
      container = null;
    }
  });

  test('should be sm', () => {
    (window as unknown as MockWindow).matchMedia.setConfig({
      type: 'screen',
      width: 700,
    })
    render(<MyComponent />, container)
  })
  test('should be md', () => {
    (window as unknown as MockWindow).matchMedia.setConfig({
      type: 'screen',
      width: 1000,
    })
    render(<MyComponent />, container)
  })
  test('should be lg', () => {
    (window as unknown as MockWindow).matchMedia.setConfig({
      type: 'screen',
      width: 1200,
    })
    render(<MyComponent />, container)
  })
})
```

package versions:

```json
"react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
"match-media-mock": "^0.1.1",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
```

Comment: Interesting that this works for you. I tried the same after noticing a similar test in react-responsive earlier. It returns all false still. Difference is I am using jest 24.8.0 and can't change that. Is a breaking change on other tests. Plus using mount from enzyme. Not entirely certain if issue lies some place else.

Comment: @kar Update answer with `react-dom` testing recipes.

Comment: Sorry I am using react-test-renderer. Updated the question under UPDATE. 
When I added the question, wasn't sure if this was a necessary info.

Comment: @kar Try to create the mock for `global.window.matchMedia` in `jest.setup.js` file as I did. Don't do it in the test case

Comment: Yup did that, same outcome.